# How do you add numbers that are under a for loop?

Tags: python

```
     charkey = input('\nWhat is the eight character key that was used in encryption?\n')
    for i in charkey:
      c = (ord(i))
      print('Asc2num',c) 

    Output: 
     What is the eight character key that was used in encryption?
    (*&^%$
    Asc2num 40
    Asc2num 42
    Asc2num 38
    Asc2num 94
    Asc2num 37
    Asc2num 36
```

I now need to add these numbers together, I have tried sum(c), but it does not work.

Comment: As it stands, you can't! After the loop, `c` is whichever number was entered last. Why don't you put them in a list, or keep adding them to some other variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use extra variable

```
charkey = input('\nWhat is the eight character key that was used in encryption?\n')
res = 0
for i in charkey:
  c = (ord(i))
  res += c

print(res)
```

Also shorter version:

```
print(sum((ord(x) for x in charkey)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**sum()** take list or any iterable object as an argument.

**Demo:**

Exception:

```
In [105]: sum(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-5771d20eddf7> in <module>()
----> 1 sum(1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Valid:

```
In [106]: sum([1,2,3,4,5])
Out[106]: 15
```

---

Create variable for addition:

**Demo:**

```
In [108]: add = 0

In [109]: for i in range(5):
   .....:     add = add + i
   .....:     

In [110]: add
Out[110]: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your question. And here is a solution

Let

```
 c=[]

 for i in charkey:
      c.append(ord(i))
 sum(c)


>>> charkey = raw_input('\nWhat is the eight character key that was used in encryption?\n')

What is the eight character key that was used in encryption?
!@#$%^&*
>>> c
[33, 64, 35, 36, 37, 94, 38, 42]
>>> sum(c)
379
```